# material-ui toggle leftnav when user clicks inside the application area

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using a toggle in my `AppBar` to show the `LeftNav`. I can close the LeftNav when the toggle is clicked again. But I also want the behavior of most of the left navs where the user clicks inside the screen and the left nav slides out. i.e click anywhere other than the LeftNav to auto close. Has anyone done this before ?

```
<LeftNav open={this.state.open} openRight="{true}">
                    <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
</LeftNav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add onRequestChange handler:

```
onRequestChange={this.onLeftNavClose.bind(this)}

onLeftNavClose(flag, reason) {
         if (!flag && reason === 'clickaway') {
            this.state.open = false; 
         }
  }
```